# How to get add remove programs list from 1 device and compare it with other device using

Tags: powershell, addremoveprograms

I have couple of remote devices, where in i need to compare the add remove programs the devices using powershell. how can i do it. Can anyone help me.

Example:-

Need to compare appremove programs from "A Computer" with "A1 Computer" and "B Computer" with "B2 Computer".

Comment: sure, that's easy enough...can you show us where you're having trouble with in your code?

Comment: $Computer = get-content "C:\computername.txt"
Get-WmiObject Win32_Product -ComputerName $Computer| select PSComputerName, Name,Version | export-csv c:\tools\Current-Installed-Applications.csv






Currently iam using above code, where in this will work only to get the addremove data from multple remote devices. 

But iam checking for data to be pulled from multiple devices and then compare.

Comment: So you want to compare the software against each computer? That makes sense if youre only comparing 2 but, if you compare multiple it doesn't make sense as far on what youre looking for. You can use `Foreach($Computer in $Computers){}` to iterate through the computers returning the data for each one. Do you have a "master" pc youd like to compare against?

Comment: in my scenario, "A computer" is master PC to "A1 Computer" and "B Computer" master PC to "B1 Computer" and similarly i have 50 master computers and 50 other computers(here each computer is master to only one other computer)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Scripting Guy [recommends](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-quickly-find-installed-software/) checking the registry instead of the very slow `Win32_Product` class. Here's their example where they search a list of computers by name:

```
$computers = Import-Csv “C:\PowerShell\computerlist.csv”
$array = @()

foreach($pc in $computers){
    $computername=$pc.computername

    #Define the variable to hold the location of Currently Installed Programs
    $UninstallKey=”SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall” 

    #Create an instance of the Registry Object and open the HKLM base key
    $reg=[microsoft.win32.registrykey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey(‘LocalMachine’,$computername) 

    #Drill down into the Uninstall key using the OpenSubKey Method
    $regkey=$reg.OpenSubKey($UninstallKey) 

    #Retrieve an array of string that contain all the subkey names
    $subkeys=$regkey.GetSubKeyNames() 

    #Open each Subkey and use GetValue Method to return the required values for each
    foreach($key in $subkeys){
        $thisKey=$UninstallKey+”\\”+$key 
        $thisSubKey=$reg.OpenSubKey($thisKey) 
        $obj = New-Object PSObject
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name “ComputerName” -Value $computername
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name “DisplayName” -Value $($thisSubKey.GetValue(“DisplayName”))
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name “DisplayVersion” -Value $($thisSubKey.GetValue(“DisplayVersion”))
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name “InstallLocation” -Value $($thisSubKey.GetValue(“InstallLocation”))
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name “Publisher” -Value $($thisSubKey.GetValue(“Publisher”))
        $array += $obj
    } 
}
$array | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName } | select ComputerName, DisplayName, DisplayVersion
```

And we can compare lists of objects with `Compare-Object` to see what software is missing from the B PCs:

```
$ComputerA = $array | Where-Object { $_.ComputerName -like 'ComputerA' } 
$ComputerB = $array | Where-Object { $_.ComputerName -like 'ComputerB' } 

Compare-Object $ComputerA $ComputerB -Property DisplayName,DisplayVersion

DisplayName            DisplayVersion SideIndicator
-----------            -------------- -------------
Notepad++ (64-bit x64) 7.8.9          <=
```